Exchange binding is not created for @Outgoing channel
I have the following setup:
@Incoming(PROCESS_VIEWS_CHANNEL)
@Outgoing(PROCESS_VIEWS_DLQ_CHANNEL)
@Acknowledgment(Strategy.MANUAL) // Enable manual ack/nack
@ActivateRequestContext
public Message<byte[]> process(Message<byte[]> message) {
  
  try {
  // some processing logic and if successful 
  return null; // to ack
  } catch(Exception e) {

   var metadata = OutgoingRabbitMQMetadata.Builder().withRoutingKey("processView.lifecycle").build();
   return message.withMetadata(Metadata.of(metadata)); // to send to the dlq
  }
} 

my properties looks the following:
# Rabbit channel configuration
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.max-outstanding-messages=1
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.connector=smallrye-rabbitmq
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.routing-keys=processView.lifecycle
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.queue.name=process-view-lifecycle-queue
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.queue.single-active-consumer=true
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.exchange.name=process-view-lifecycle-exchange
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.exchange.type=direct

# Rabbit mq dlq configuration
mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.connector=smallrye-rabbitmq
mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.default-routing-key=processView.lifecycle
mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.exchange.name=process-view-lifecycle-dlx
mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.queue.name=process-view-lifecycle-dlq
mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.exchange.type=direct

the problem now, is that the failed messages are not routed correctly to the outgoing exchange, i.e. process-view-lifecycle-dlx. Looking at the management ui of rabbitmq using the dev services, I find that the incoming exchange is always created eagerly and properly bound to the queue. But the outgoing exchange is only created when a message is sent and failed and then it has no binding to the queue.
so what is the issue here?
I want to use this exchange as a sink for all failed messages and then later I will have job that consume those messages.
if you ask why I am not using the dlq of rabbit itself, it is because this feature is not supported currently within my org setup for rabbit. so We have to do this custom dlx/dlq stuff.

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79156390/quarkus-reactive-messaging-exception-handler/79158188#79158188

Indeed the outgoing channel declares the exchange it produces to (unless exchange.declare is set to false) after the broker connection is established, which is attempted lazily at the first outgoing message.
Also the mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.queue.name=process-view-lifecycle-dlq won't do anything as the outgoing channel doesn't define any queue.name  attribute.
If I understood correctly, you don't want to create the queue with DLX args.
If you can skip the declaration of your consumed queue, and do it separately (For dev purposes, the Quarkus RabbitMQ devservice lets you declare queues via quarkus.rabbitmq.devservices.queues property), I think there is a way to configure the incoming channel to only declare and bind dlx and dlq:
When an incoming channel is started, if the auto-bind-dlq is set to true, it declares the dead-letter-exchange, the dead-letter-queue and binds them together. However, that also configures the x-dead-letter-exchange arguments of the consumed queue. You can skip the queue declaration with ``queue.declare=false`. So your config should look like this:
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.max-outstanding-messages=1
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.connector=smallrye-rabbitmq
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.routing-keys=processView.lifecycle
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.queue.name=process-view-lifecycle-queue
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.queue.single-active-consumer=true
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.exchange.name=process-view-lifecycle-exchange
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.exchange.type=direct
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.queue.declare=false
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.auto-bind-dlq=true
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.dlx.declare=true
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.dead-letter-exchange=process-view-lifecycle-dlx
mp.messaging.incoming.processviews.dead-letter-queue-name=process-view-lifecycle-dlq


mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.connector=smallrye-rabbitmq
mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.default-routing-key=processView.lifecycle
mp.messaging.outgoing.processviewsdlq.exchange.name=process-view-lifecycle-dlx

Hope this helps to clarify the subject.

thanks for your answer. given my use of the @outgoing channel that is a just an exchange with a queue that should be bound to it, Why do I need all this dead-letter-exchange/queue stuff? shouldn't I be able to route the message to that outbound channel with just declaring the exchange in the outgoing properties ?
or is this related to the fact that messages are routed there on failure ?

and one more question, the documentation doesn't mention that I need to have queue.name for the outgoing link. it only mentions that the exchange name is needed. See the part here with the existing queues and exchanges: https://quarkus.io/guides/rabbitmq-reference#configuring-the-rabbitmq-exchangequeue. I find this to be truly confusing.
